# How to accept user input as a string in C++?

Tags: c++

I made a code asking for user input of either "yes" or "no". However when I try to print out the user input, nothing prints. I am pretty sure I made a simple mistake but I am not what exactly I did wrong.

```
string choice;

cout << "Type [yes] or [no]: ";
getline (cin, choice);
cout << choice;
```

The only output I get is:

```
Type [yes] or [no]: yes
```

Comment: This code isn't obviously wrong on its own, so the problem depends on the surrounding context. Can you please provide a full [mcve]. At a guess, you might simply not be flushing the output, though that would happen at the end of your program anyway... Try this: `std::cout << choice << std::flush;` Note that most implementations will flush by default when you print a new line.

Comment: Did you press enter after entering yes? Because `getline` will wait for a new line before returning.

Comment: (Some people might recommend `std::endl`, but [I think those people are wrong](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2619).)

Comment: @BobTFish std::flush worked !! thank you!

Comment: @Christina Interesting! So what happens when your program finishes? It should always flush the buffer when the program exits cleanly, so you should see the text even if it is a bit delayed.